# Python MySQLdb connecting error

Tags: python, mysql-python

I want to transfer my data from json into mysql for that I install the python library MySQLdb . It import successfully but it gives error while connecting

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="king123",db="thangs")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="king123",db="thangs")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")

>>> import _mysql
>>> db=_mysql.connect()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    db=_mysql.connect()
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)")
```

> > > db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="rat123",db="thangs",host="localhost",port=1028,user="mroot")

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="king123",db="thangs",host="localhost",port=1028,user="munieb")


File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
OperationalError: (2013, "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 2")
```

Comment: Is your mysql database running on the same computer on port 10061?

Comment: no, but mysql php admin is also installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the [server and point](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/private/_mysql-module.html#connect).

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(passwd="king123",db="thangs",host="hostname",port=3251,user="user")
```

Comment: OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'hostname' (0)") it give the following error

Comment: Well, you have to change it to match the server you want to use... Get the information of your database. I can't tell you what that is...

Comment: how I get my database info ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for me, the problem was with ip address which mysql listened to port 3305 on. By `netstat -aon` I saw:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
...
TCP    0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       884
...
```

So I uncommented line below in `my.ini` config file:

```
#bind-address="127.0.0.1"
```

then restarted mysql and problem gone!